# How to get SQL Row Name in Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

How do I get a Rows name in Python? I'm using import sqlite3.
Is there a way I can add some code in the "Name" spot and make it change to the first Row of a Table so I don't need Name to be there? I want Name to be there and just have it set it to the Row 0 Name like I have in SQLite DB Browser. I want to use this to make able to connect with my other DBs instead of making a new .py and changing the names in the print below.

`print(f"\Name: {row[0]}\n")`

Comment: include your code please, it's very hard to tell you what to do exactly without it.

Comment: I just want to replace where it says Name with a bit of code so Name just changed to the Row Name is there a way like row(0).Name or something?

Comment: ```def print_all_data():
    rows = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM info;",)
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        print(f"\Name: {row[0]}\nAge: {row[1]}\n")```

Comment: OK - I know what you mean and will post an answer, but you should definetly look up how post a question properly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the cursor, so that the datastructure the rows get cached in after beeing fetched from the Database will be a **dictionary** instead of a **list**.

In order to do so you can add the following argument to when instantiating the **cursor-object**:

```
cursor = conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
```

Afterwards, you can simply access your table columns via their names - without having to memorize the indices of each row.

Comment: How can I use this? Can you give me an example? Dont know if this is what I wanted though.